# How to get value from one TextBox to another TextBox using Tab Index

Tags: c#, winforms

I know its a silly question but, still I wanted to know it. I have two textboxes, textbox1 and textbox2. I entered some text in textbox1. Now I want that the value of textbox one should be displayed on textbox2 when I move from textbox1 to textbox2 using tab index or by clicking my mouse on textbox2. I know I can make us of the mouse over event. But it will be great if I get some good opinion from you. Thanks in advance

Comment: asp.net or winforms? Why is the question tagged as both?

Comment: Copy the content from textBox1 to textBox2 on textBox2 GotFocus event.

Comment: have you tried lostfocus or gotfocus?

Comment: I am not able to get the GotFocus Event, thats y I asked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }

    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

Comment: MouseEnter is not the correct event here. It will be triggered when you move the mouse over the control, even when not focusing it. And it will not be triggered if you use the tab key to focus the control.

Comment: Eh... To which events are those methods subscribed? Simply removing the `Mouse` part from the method name doesn't change the event being used...

Comment: I have not removed the "Mouse" part from event..these are actual events of Textbox check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events.aspx

Comment: Need to add some tip to this. We should try to avoid writing logic in Leave Event unless it is unavoidable as many of times this event create different types of situations and some times it creates a infinite loop kind situation if enter and leave both events are used. However, we can make use of the Enter Leave event. Which is same as GotFocus Event. Thank you for your help....